# Using async to run multiple methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Lets say I have this code:

```
public async void Init(){
    init1();
    init2();
    init3();     
}
```

First question is are they running asynchronously or not?  The methods themselves are `public void` not `async`.

Second question is how do I make sure they're running `async` and to know when they're finished? Like this..

```
public async void Init(){
    init1();
    init2();
    init3();     
    await ... all finished
}
```

Third, when I call `Init()` elsewhere, can it not be wrapped by an `async` method? Like this code below, or does it have to be `async`?

```
public async void Init(){
    init1();
    init2();
    init3();   
}

public void doIt(){
  Init();
}
```

Comment: Side note: `void Foo` [can't be await'ed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx#BKMK_VoidReturnType), so really not much difference difference in usage whether it is `async` or not... Trying to reason about behavior of such method should cause pain...

Comment: This one page will answer pretty much all your questions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I did look at that already, and even though it helps with using httpclient, and methods that `return` data, but not what I'm asking.

Comment: Well, 1. your init methods are not Tasks or awaited so they will run synchronously. 2. Make them all Tasks and use `WaitAll`, 3. yes, NOTE: you should not be using async with voids (unless its an event handler) you should be using the TPL logic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that should help.

> First question is are they running asynchronously or not?

No, and you didn't really need to ask this on Stack Overflow because the compiler itself will give you a warning that explicitly states your method will run synchronously.

> Second question is how do I make sure they're running async and to know when they're finished?

First, your methods need to be properly asynchronous:

```
async Task init1Async();
async Task init2Async();
async Task init3Async();
```

Then you can make the caller invoke them *concurrently* and then *asynchronously* wait for them all to complete:

```
async Task InitAsync() {
  var task1 = init1Async();
  var task2 = init2Async();
  var task3 = init3Async();
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
}
```

> Third, when I call Init() elsewhere, can it not be wrapped by an async method?

Once your `InitAsync` method is properly defined as returning a `Task`, it can be naturally consumed using `await`:

```
async Task doItAsync() {
  await InitAsync();
}
```

Note that this *does* require the caller to be `async`.

Also recommended reading: my [Best Practices for Asynchronous Code MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), particularly the sections on "avoid async void" and "async all the way".

Comment: Lol I actually stumbled across your page before this and checked out the examples.  Your answer here pretty much sums it up.  However, if I don't make each method `async init1Async()` can I just use `Task.Run` in the `InitAsync()`? If so, would `InitAsync()` also have to be `async` to use `Task.Run`?

Comment: +1. @ZeeTee No if you don't `await` call to `Task.Run` you should not mark method `async` (as Stephen Cleary pointed out if you'd be looking at compiler warning you'd see warning about it too).

Comment: @ZeeTee: In general, you should avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET. If you have naturally synchronous (e.g., CPU-bound) work to do, just call it directly without `async`/`await` or `Task.Run`. If you have naturally asynchronous (e.g., I/O-bound) work to do, call the asynchronous API using `async`/`await`, but without using `Task.Run`. P.S. I have an [MSDN article on `async` ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) that just came out a couple days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Also One Thing you can do await on each on the methods to get the required result of each methods.

```
var task1 = await init1Async();
var task2 = await  init2Async();
var task3 = await init3Async();
```